# Prevent forwarding or replying to email

Tags: xpages

Is there a way to prevent an external recipient from replying to an email, we need them to update our portal. In the ReplyTo Field we add "please update our portal with your response" but many users ignore it by changing the ReplyTo Field.

We create the problem as we add a full description of our customer update in the body rather than just adding a link. I don't really wish to remove this additional information as it is more user friendly. Access to the portal and their 'ticket' is extremely user friendly, one click, it is just people being lazy.

This is how the email is generated.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

```
var recipient = document1.getItemValueString("emailField");
var sendergroup = "support@ourcompany.co.uk"; 
var memo = database.createDocument();
memo.appendItemValue("Form","Memo");
//memo.appendItemValue("Principal","Support Request@NotesDomain");// Don't use.
memo.appendItemValue("From",sendergroup);
memo.appendItemValue("INetFrom",sendergroup);
memo.appendItemValue("ReplyTo","... please update our portal with your response.");
memo.appendItemValue("DisplaySent",sendergroup);
memo.appendItemValue("SMTPOriginator",sendergroup);
memo.appendItemValue("Subject", Our references here ");

var rtitem:NotesRichTextItem = memo.createRichTextItem("Body");
var rtStyle:NotesRichTextStyle = session.createRichTextStyle();
rtitem.addNewLine();
rtitem.appendText("Hi "+firstname+",");
rtitem.addNewLine();
rtitem.appendText("Details of the request in here..");
rtitem.addNewLine();
rtitem.appendText("https://link to their document in here");
memo.send(recipient);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot control what happens at the recipient's mail system....

However, you *could* use a sender/reply address where the mail goes to a mailin database where you could have an agent send them a reply stating that their reply is ignored and that they will have to open the link....

Not ideal - but then at least they know :-)

Comment: Thanks John. We accept initial requests into a mailin database so that probably wouldn't work but I do appreciate your help.